# How do I tell Java to map a logical font (e.g. SansSerif) to a specific font on my system?

Tags: java, fonts

Is there a way to map a logical font (e.g. SansSerif) to a different font when running a Java program? If so, does the method differ between Java VM versions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/fontconfig.properties` for everything (well, almost) you'd ever want to know about font mapping in Java. :-)

Comment: "fontconfig.properties.src" is the readable version